# Processing large XML files using .NET 3.5

Tags: c#, .net, xml

What is the "recommended" approach for processing very large XML files in .NET 3.5?

For writing, I want to generate an element at a time then append to a file.

For reading, I would likewise want to read an element at a time (in the same order as written).

I have a few ideas how to do it using strings and File.Append, but does .NET 3.5 provide XML Api's for dealing with arbitrarily large XML files?

Comment: If you ever find yourself thinking of processing XML as strings, please stop. That's not just advice for .NET, it's for any platform. Any platform worth its salt these days will tend to have at least two supported XML APIs - one for DOM manipulation, and another for streaming. Use those, and save yourself (and anyone who hopes to inter-operate with you) from a world of pain.

Comment: That's a somewhat naive view. XML's are commonly serialized to and from strings which is "processing". Certain circumstances warrant it such as generating large (simple) XMLs on slower devices (which is the case I'm referring to). An experienced developer would not undergo a "world of pain" to deal with XMLs in such circumstance.

Comment: As I say, there are two general APIs that should be found (DOM and streaming) that should address most needs. And I disagree - serialization to and from string is just that - serialization - not processing. You can't have encountered much hand-rolled XML processing code of the kind I've seen though - stuff that treats `<elem></elem>` and `<elem/>` as different, stuff that can only cope with namespaced code if the prefix is the one expected, etc.

Comment: Or, to put it another way - if you are in such a resource constrained environment that you can't use an XML api, don't pretend to produce XML - produce something simpler such as CSV. Don't make promises that you can't keep.

Comment: If only life were that simple. I've never been able to get paid explaining to the customer that they "can't" have something because of hardware "limitations". The reality is it HAS to work, and if a device needs to generate a (large) XML to interact with an external system, appending (or bulk appending) strings to a file may be appropriate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Without going into specifics this isn't easy to answer. .NET offers different methods to process XML files:

- [XmlDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx) creates a DOM, supports XPath queries but loads the entire XML file into memory.
- [XElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.aspx)/[XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx) has support for LINQ and also reads the entire XML file into memory.
- [XmlReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.aspx) is a forward-only reader. It does not read the entire file into memory.
- [XmlWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwriter.aspx) is just like the XmlReader, except for writing

Based on what you say an XmlReader/XmlWriter combination seems like the best approach.

Answer (score 1):

As Dirk said, using an XmlWriter/XmlReader combo sounds like the best approach. It can be very lengthy and if your XML file is fairly complex it gets very unwieldy. I had to do something similar recently with some strict memory constraints. [My SO question might come in handy.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16191015/copying-appending-an-element-to-an-xml-document-without-buffering-to-ram)

But personally, I found this method [here on MSDN blogs](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mfussell/archive/2005/02/12/371546.aspx) to be very easy to implement and it neatly handles appending to the end of the XML file without fragments.

Answer (score 0):

Try to make an *.xsd file out of your *.xml. You can than generate *.cs file from *.xsd file. After that load you *.xml file to your object. It should take less memory than whole file.

There is a plugin for VS2010 that gives option to generate *.cs file from *.xsd. It is called XSD2Code. In that plugin you have an option to decorate properties for serialization. For your *.xsd file named Settings you would get Settings.cs. You would than do something like this.

```
StreamReader str = new StreamReader("SomeFolder\\YourFile.xml");
XmlSerializer xmlSer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TcpPostavke));
Settings m_settings = (Settings )xmlSer .Deserialize(str);
```

You can than query your list of objects with Linq.